# Is there a difference in scoring between the Xbox and Wii/Playstation versions?

Tags: just-dance-3, just-dance-series

(This question only applies should apply to any game Just Dance 3 and on, but I'm specifically asking about JD3.)

The Xbox versions of Just Dance are able to use the Kinect, which means the player's full body is tracked, and not just the player's right hand. This means that the player can score on more moves, since some moves use the left hand.

Because of this, is there a difference in scoring between the consoles (for example, a Perfect on the Xbox gives 50 points, but a Perfect on the Wii/Playstation gives 100?)

Comment: Which game, specifically? (There are several, though I expect the answer to be "yes" in any case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, yes and no.

According to the trivia section on [Just Dance Wikia's page for the game](http://justdance.wikia.com/wiki/Just_Dance_3):

> On Wii and PlayStation 3, to get a star, you just have to copy the hand movements while on Kinect, you have to copy the moves with your body. This is because that on Wii and PlayStation 3, the moves done with left hand don't give points since you can only hold the Wii Remote or the PS Move controller in your right hand.
> This is actually the only (at least clear) nerfing of Kinect points,
> due to the fact that the Kinect sometimes scores many more moves than
> other consoles. However, this is not the case for all routines.

No, the basic points per move are not changed, but getting a Perfect is harder on a Kinect than it is on the Wii or PS3, which balances it out.